# Gramática: predicado nominal o predicado verbal

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, verbos, cópulas

> Lucia **está** en la cama con fiebre desde el martes.

En mi libro “está” lo analiza como predicado nominal. Pero si yo quiero sustituir y hacer una prueba con el verbo *quedarse* por ejemplo, el significado de la frase no cambia. ¿Porqué “está” no es predicado verbal?

Comment: el significado de la frase no cambia, pero sí la aportación del verbo al significado de la misma

Comment: *Quedar* es mas o menos equivalente a *estar*, pero *quedarse* es diferente.

Answer (score 1):

En la oración:

> - Lucia está en la cama con fiebre desde el martes.

"está en la cama con fiebre desde el martes" es, sin lugar a dudas, un predicado verbal por la presencia del verbo "estar".

El predicado es no verbal (nominal, adjetivo, adverbial) cuando, por omisión del verbo, el núcleo del predicado es, respectivamente, un sustantivo (o frase nominal), un adjetivo (o frase adjetiva) o un adverbio (o frase adverbial):

- El niño, afiebrado / con fiebre (predicado adjetivo).
- El niño, allí / en la cama (predicado adverbial).
- El niño, mi única preocupación (predicado nominal).

Algunos autores también hablan de predicados verboidales, donde el núcleo del predicado es un verboide (infinitivo, gerundio, participio):

- ¿El niño, salir con este frío? (*O tal vez mejor:* ¿Salir con este frío el niño?) Es una locura.
- El niño, volando de fiebre.
- El niño, acostado.

Answer (score 1):

En tu frase, "está en la cama con fiebre desde el martes" es un predicado verbal.

Un predicado nominal está formado por un verbo copulativo (un verbo prácticamente vacío de significado cuya función es básicamente la de unir) y un atributo, por ejemplo, "es feliz": "es" es el verbo copulativo y "feliz" el atributo. Como explica el blog de recursos educativos [*La guía 2000*](https://lengua.laguia2000.com/verbos/ser-y-estar-como-verbos-predicativos), el verbo "estar" frecuentemente actúa como verbo copulativo y, por tanto, va acompañado de un atributo y forma con él un predicado nominal. Es lo que ocurre, por ejemplo, en la frase

> La madre de María está enfadada.

Pero, cuando el verbo "estar" se utiliza para expresar la idea de "estar en un lugar", entonces no asume el papel de verbo copulativo y forma parte de un predicado verbal. Esto es lo que pasa en la frase

> Ayer estuve en casa de Ana.

Lo mismo ocurre en tu frase,

> Lucía está en la cama con fiebre desde el martes,

"está en la cama con fiebre" es predicado verbal. Y si construyes una frase parecida con "quedarse"

> Lucía se ha quedado en la cama con fiebre desde el martes,

pasa lo mismo: el predicado, "se ha quedado en la cama con fiebre desde el martes", es verbal.

Answer (score -1):

No es lo mismo, no tiene el mismo significado, hay un pequeño matiz de diferencia.

Si analizas la frase:
http://www.rinconcastellano.com/gramatica/sintagma_verbal_predicado.html#

La clave está en el `se` de `quedarse`.